# React: Error styled components no aplica estilos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy aprendiendo react, y como aplicar estilos usando styled-components, instale el paquete utilizando el codigo getting started en la pagina oficial de styled-components e instale el paquete.

```
npm install --save styled-components
```

Sin embargo, me dio el siguiente error despues de instalarlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente realizar un npm audit fix, sin embargo eso empeora los errores, y luego no me permite ni inicializar el servidor local.
Sin embargo, si continuo e intento hacer el ejercicio colocando un estilo sencillo a un componente no lo aplica pero si muestra el componente.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export default function ComponentesEstilizados(){

    const myH1 = styled.h1`
        padding: 2rem;
        text-align: center;
        color: blue;
    `;


    return(
        <>
            <h1>Hola</h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme no encuentro nada al respecto, muchas gracias.

Comment: tienes que usar el componente estilizado... `<myH1>Hola</myH1>`

Answer (score 0):

Cuando creas componentes debes reemplazar las etiquetas HTML por la del componente que vas a utilizar, quedaría así:

```
return(
        <>
            <myH1>Hola</myH1>
        </>
    )
```

Tienes que hacer lo mismo con los demás componentes que vayas creando.